# Where can I find a collection of synonyms with detailed explanations of their nuances or differences?

Tags: english

Online sources, like some sites, and books both are OK. (English vocabulary)

To clarify, I'm not asking for a method to search for synonyms. Rather, I'm finding some sources which I can browse in my leisure time to pick up some useful or interesting synonyms and their nuances, kind of like a textbook stuff.

Comment: Did you consider a same-language dictionary for this purpose? For example, in French, *balle* and *ballon* both mean 'ball'. The difference in usage is explained pretty clearly to me in https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/balle/7690

Comment: @Brandin What do you mean by 'same-language dictionary'? I want sources with English explanations.

Comment: For English vocabulary, then you would use a dictionary in English, and the explanations will be in English. It's also called an English-English dictionary, or a monolingual dictionary. I guess I'm not sure how what you're looking for would be different than looking up two words (the two synonyms you are comparing) in your favourite English language dictionary, in order to learn the different nuances.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely find [***WordHippo***](https://www.wordhippo.com/) useful. It gives definitions to the different connotations of each word and gives a wide range of synonyms for each connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Of course Merriam-Webster dictionary is always helpful, but if you're every working on a Macbook, you can actually force touch a word on the trackpad, and it will generate synonyms on a word.

On google, you can always right click the word and press the "Search google for x" option and it'll give you all the related synonyms and definitions.

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness in the question. To clarify, I'm not asking for a method to search for synonyms. Rather, I'm finding some sources which I can browse in my leisure time to pick up some useful or interesting synonyms and their nuances, kind of like a textbook stuff.